# Join/Subquery is fast/slow depending on which column I filter on (not a simple index issue)

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, subquery, postgresql-performance

PostgreSQL 9.3.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit

Each customer can have many orders and referrals. Now, I want to create a view with some statistics for customer where, for each customer, I have some calculated columns (one row for each customer).

**Create the view:**

```
create view myview
select
    a.customer_id,
    sum(a.num) as num_orders,
    sum(b.num) as num_referrals
from
    (
    select
        customer.id as customer_id,
        count(customer.id) as num
    from
        customer
    left join
        order
    on
        order.customer_id = customer.id
    group by
        customer.id
    ) a
left join
    (
    select
        customer.id as customer_id,
        count(customer.id) as num
    from
        customer
    left join
        referral
    on
        referral.customer_id = customer.id
    group by
        customer.id
    ) b
on
    a.customer_id = b.customer_id
group by
    a.customer_id,
    b.customer_id
;
```

**Query A** (this is fast):

```
select
    customer.*,
    myview.*
from
    customer
left join
    myview
on
    customer.id = myview.customer_id
where
    customer.id = 100
;
```

**Query B** (this is SLOW):

```
select
    customer.*,
    myview.*
from
    customer
left join
    myview
on
    customer.id = myview.customer_id
where
    customer.sex = 'M'
;
```

**Query C** (this is fast):

```
select
    customer.*,
    myview.*
from
    customer
left join
    myview
on
    customer.id = myview.customer_id
where
    (select id from customer where sex = 'M')
;
```

OK, so why is Query B so much different than Query A in terms of performance? I guess, in Query B, it is running those subqueries first without filtering, but I don't know how to fix it.

The problem is that it is our ORM that is generating the query. So, I can't fix the problem by doing something like Query C.
I'm hoping there's just a better way to design my view to fix the problem. The main difference in the `EXPLAIN` results between Query A and Query B is that Query B has some `MERGE RIGHT JOIN` operations.
Any ideas?

---

EDIT:

I added following information per requests from people commenting. The following is the more true-to-life info (as opposed to the simplified, hypothetical scenario above).

```
create or replace view myview as
select
    a.id_worder,
    count(a.*) as num_finance_allocations,
    count(b.*) as num_task_allocations
from
    (
    select
        woi.id_worder,
        count(*) as num
    from
        worder_invoice woi
    left join
        worder_finance_task ct
    on
        ct.id_worder_finance = woi.id
    left join 
        worder_finance_task_allocation cta
    on
        cta.id_worder_finance_task = ct.id
    group by
        woi.id_worder
    ) a
left join
    (
    select
        wot.id_worder,
        count(*) as num
    from
        worder_task wot
    left join
        worder_task_allocation wota
    on
        wota.id_worder_task = wot.id
    group by
        wot.id_worder
    ) b
on
    a.id_worder = b.id_worder
group by
    a.id_worder,
    b.id_worder
;
```

**Query A** (fast, apparently I need a rep of more than 10 to post more than 2 links, so no EXPLAIN for this one)

```
select 
    *
from 
    worder a 
left outer join 
    myview b 
on 
    a.id = b.id_worder 
where 
    a.id = 100
;
```

**Query B** (SLOW, [EXPLAIN](http://explain.depesz.com/s/Y6l7))

```
select 
    *
from 
    worder a 
left outer join 
    myview b 
on 
    a.id = b.id_worder 
where 
    a.id_customer = 200
```

**Query C** (fast, [EXPLAIN](http://explain.depesz.com/s/prF9))

```
select 
    *
from 
    worder a 
left outer join 
    myview b 
on 
    a.id = b.id_worder 
where 
    a.id = (select id from worder where id_customer = 200)
;
```

Comment: In the explains, Query B and Query C use the same exact indexes for all tables?

Comment: For non-trivial performance questions, you need to provide more basic information. Consider instructions in the [tag info for \[postgresql-performance\]](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). For starters: `order` is a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and cannot be used like you display.

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE for all queries?

Comment: @TabAlleman, yes they are the same, with the exception of Query C having an extra index scan on Customer table at the beginning.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, the example I gave above is a simplified hypothetical example. I guess I hoped it was kind of a generic SQL question. I can post the EXPLAIN results, but it would have different table and column names, etc... so I figured it would be pointless. Do you think it would still be of use?

Comment: Well thanks for your replies guys. @ErwinBrandstetter, I'm going to go back and provide the 'real' info instead of hypothetical so I can post some meaningful EXPLAIN results, etc.  Working on gathering all the info now then will go back and edit my original post.

Comment: Alright, I updated my post with more info including EXPLAINs.  It would only allow me to post two links to the explains though, so one is missing. I had to obfuscate things, hopefully I didn't screw anything up.

Comment: Were you able to take a look at my code and implement it in your "real world" scenario?

Comment: Hi @JoeLove, thanks for your response. I have not had a chance to check it out yet. On a different project today. Hopefully tonight or tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rewriting your view like so:

```
create view myview
select
    c.customer_id,
    (
        select count(*) from order o where o.customer_id=c.customer_id
    ) num_orders,
    (
        select count(*) from referral r where r.customer_id=c.customer_id
    )
    from customer c ;
```

Comment: Wow! So, as I said earlier, my examples were heavily simplified. For example, here I was only pulling two simple calculated columns. In reality, I'm doing several complex calculated columns.
Your suggestion here of making each column a subquery seemed crazy. How could that possibly be more efficient. But I'll be damned if that didn't fix the problem. It sure is a lot of redundant writing, but totally worth it considering the performance gain I'm seeing. Thanks!

Comment: It works because it's simplified and everything's based on customer instead of unions that all have to be ran individually and separately. This view can more likely use the indexes on the customer table.